# Ring with unity Question

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let R be a commutative ring with unity.

(i) Prove that the set of non-zero elements which are not zero divisors
is closed under multiplication.

R has unity so its non empty. pick a and b in R.
want to show that ab is in R for all a,b $\in R$

we know there are no zero divisors in our ring but lets assume abc=0 we know that a is not a zero divisor thus  $bc= 0 $ we know since b is in R b is not a zero divisor so $c= 0$  which leads us to c is a zero divisor thus c is not in our ring. so ab does not equal 0 for all a and b in our ring. thus ab is not a zero divisor in our ring for all a,b.

(ii) Give an explicit example of a ring R where this set above, together
with 0, is not a subring. Explain your answer.

EDIT:

$U_{12}$ satisfy's above but is not closed under addition ie 5+5 = 10 10 isn't in the ring but 5 is

Comment: No, $a^{-1}$ does not necessarily exist! (E.g. in $\Bbb Z$ except for $0$ there are no zero divisors, but only $\pm1$ are invertible. For the other one, if you mean $U_{12}=\Bbb Z_{12}$, then yes. Also, in $\Bbb Z_4$, we have $1\in S$ (where $S$ is the set of non-zero-divisors, which is *not a ring*!), but $1+1\notin S$.

Comment: There is no need to use the word «question» in the title of questions...

Comment: Im confused $Z_{12}$ has [10] in it it just happens to be a zero divisor for certain numbers  $U_{12}$ makes you land on an element that doesn't exist i thought that would prove it?

Comment: The tags don't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Let $a$ and $b$ be *non-zero-divisors*, then try to prove that $ab$ is not a zero divisor, too: For that end, assume that $abc=0$, as $a$ is not a zero divisor, but $a(bc)=0$, by definition, we have that $bc=0$. As $b$ is not a zero divisor, it implies $c=0$. This proves that neither $ab$ is a zero divisor.

(ii) Do you know any (finite) ring with zero divisors? Try to prove that its set of non-zero-divisors is not closed under addition.